# Caching CCAnimation

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

Is there perhaps some best practice to caching CCAnimations in Cocos2D? Currently I am basically recalculating an "appear" animation for a sprite every time it appears on the screen. Wouldn't it be wise to cache the animation in the instance class somehow?

Currently, I run this code like thousands of times for some given game conditions:

```c
CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
[frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"WichserAnimations.plist"];

NSMutableArray* frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
for (int i = 41; i <= 48; i++) {
    NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"intro_prep__Main_000%i.png", i];
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = [frameCache spriteFrameByName:file];
    [frames addObject:frame];
}

CCAnimation* anim    = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:0.05f];
CCAnimate*   connect = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];        
[self runAction:connect];
```

I thought of putting the "connect" CCAnimate object into the sprite for later re-use, but this does not seem to work :( any advice will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation cache class is called `CCAnimationCache`.